# After plus tenses

Tags: grammar

I sort of remember being taught in school that after 'after' I should use present perfect. Is that a rule or is past simple also ok?
For example should I say: 'After I have told them they looked at me.' or 'After I told them they looked at me.'? And if I started with 'After I had told them' should I follow up with 'they looked at me'?

Comment: Hi.  There are problems with your question. 1. You have remembered inaccurately.  2. It is possible to use almost any tense after 'after' depending on the context. 3. There are many EFL resources online that explain the use of  'after' and tense. Perhaps you could edit your question to address one example together with some context that indicate what you want it to mean.  Regards

Comment: For example, wouldn't 'After I have watched the movie, I turned off the TV.' be more grammatically correct than 'After I watched the movie, I turned off the TV.' because there are two actions, one happening before the other, first watching the movie, then turning off the TV.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to use "after I told . . ." or other simple past tense verb, or present perfect, past perfect, and others.